# Почему Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation? (Element.classList)

Tags: javascript

Поясните пожалуйста, почему следующий код:

```js
Element.prototype.addClass = function() {
  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return Element.prototype.classList.add.apply(this, args);
};

document.body.addClass('first', 'two');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0s5gptfb/

вызывает ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`?

<s>Что-то с контекстом?</s>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Что происходит?**

Метод `Element.prototype.classList.add` принадлежит интерфейсу [`DomTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList), и должен вызываться в контексте `DomTokenList` (в вашем случае [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)).

Внутри метода `Element.prototype.addClass` переменная `this` указывает на экземпляр [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element), иными словами, вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `add` в контексте неправильного объекта.

**Что делать?**

Нужно передавать правильный контекст методу `Element.prototype.classList.add`. Например так:

```
Element.prototype.addClass = function() {
    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    return this.classList.add.apply(this.classList, args);
};

document.body.addClass('first', 'two');
```

А вот и рабочий [пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8t1m48c/).